# Python code error in program should calculate the monthly average price for Google and tell us the best and worst six-month period for Google

Tags: python

I need help to figure out how to fix errors in my Python code Assignment.
Basically I need create a program that should calculate the monthly average price for Google and tell us the best and worst six-month period for Google.
The average price is defined as ((v1*c1)+(v2*c2)+(v3*c3)+(v4*c4)...+(vn*cn)) / (v1+v2+v3+v4...+vn) where vi is the volume for day i and ci is the adjusted close price for day i.
For this assignment we'll look at Google from 2004 to 2012. The data-set we'll need is a table in CSV format and can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/qr7cu2kui654kgz/googlePrices.csv.

So far I've created the Python code below but it's show some errors message and I couldn't figure out.

Thank you in advance.

Regards, 
Roberto Leal

============================================================
Code:

```
__author__ = 'Roberto'

def get_values():

import operator

data_file = open("googlePrices.csv")


def get_data_list(file_name):
    data_list = []  # always start with an open list
    for line_str in data_file:
        data_list.append(line_str.strip().split(','))  # removes all commas from the csv file
    return data_list


def monthlyAverage(list_of_tuples=[]):


    averageList = []
    currentYear_int = 2012
    month_int = 11
    sum_float = float()
    count = 0

    for a_tuple in list_of_tuples:
        dateStr = a_tuple[0]
        Floatdata = a_tuple[1]
        listdate = dateStr.split(',')
        Year_int = int(listdate[0])
        month_int = int(listdate[1])
        date_year_str = "Date: " + str(month_int) + "-" + str(currentYear_int)

    if month_int != currentYear_int:
        float_average = sum_float / count
        list_average = [date_year_str , float_average]
        average_tuple = tuple(list_average)
        averageList.append(average_tuple)
        current_month_int = month_int
        sum_float = 0.0
        count = 0
        sum_float += Floatdata
        count += 1

    return averageList


def best_6_month(averageList):
    averageList.sort()
    print("The 6 best months fo google are: ")
    print()
    print(averageList)


def worst_6_month(averageList):
    averageList.reverse()
    print("The 6 worst months for google are: ")
    print()
    print(averageList)


optionStr = ""

if optionStr != "0":
    print("------------------------------")
    print("\n Google Stock Prices. 2004 - 2012")
    print("------------------------------")
    print("Please choose an option")
    print()
    print("1.    Calculate Average")
    print("2.    View best six months")
    print("3.    View worst six months")
    print("0.    Exit program")
    print()

optionStr = input("Enter you choice now: ")
if (len(optionStr) != 1) or (optionStr not in "0123"):
    print("You have entered an invalid number!")
    print("Please try again")

elif optionStr == "1":
    monthlyAverage()

elif optionStr == "2":
    best_6_month()

elif optionStr == "3":
    worst_6_month()

elif optionStr == "0":
    print("\n Exiting program... Goodbye.")

else:
    print("\n Bad option")
```

===============================================================

```
Error:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Kate/Desktop/College DIT/projecttest1/Project_3.py", line 97, in <module>
        best_6_month()
    TypeError: best_6_month() missing 1 required positional argument: 'averageList'

    Process finished with exit code 1



    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Kate/Desktop/College DIT/projecttest1/Project_3.py", line 94, in <module>
        monthlyAverage()
      File "C:/Users/Kate/Desktop/College DIT/projecttest1/Project_3.py", line 48, in monthlyAverage
        list_average = [date_year_str , float_average]`enter code here`
    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'date_year_str' referenced before assignment

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: "best_6_month() missing 1 required positional argument: 'averageList'". Well, it looks like you're calling `best_6_month()` without any arguments.

Comment: Hi Morgan, sorry I just start learning Python at college, could you please explain with more details (where my code is wrong and how to fix that ) I would appreciate your help.  thanks